# Sonarqube pl/sql custom rule type

Tags: plsql, sonarqube

I am developing custom rules for z pl/sql analyzer. All new rules come out as code smells. How to make rule a bug, not a code smell?

Comment: Possibly it'd be helpful to have one of those _custom rules for z pl/sql analyzer_ as an example in your question description? – You may also want to rephrase your question title into a question like _How can I make my custom Sonarqube pl/sql rule report as a 'bug' instead of a 'code smell'?_; or similar. See also [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/5698098) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It is done by adding

```
import org.sonar.plsqlopen.checks.Tags;
```

and

```
tags = {Tags.BUG}
```

to rule definition.

Comment: If you add one of those custom rules in your question description as an example then you can re-use that example in your own answer here to show a complete and working example.